# how to show progress bar in vb.net asp.net while process long

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, process, progress-bar

I had a SQL Stored Procedure that get a mbd file and import it using itself in less than 3 second but because of the security of the shared server I can't do it anymore but instead I can use vb.net to import necessary temp tables to Sql server and continue the process
 Unfortunately it gets so long to complete the process (about 3 minutes for a 3MegaByte mdb file), and I need to show client the process so the client can wait patiently and know how far the process has gone.
I have seen many things related to this but they are all showing an image loading instead of exact progress bar,
My question is: Is there any possible way to show the progress bar while based on how the process is doing?
PS: I can place the show progress percent in my for loop in vb.net.


EDIT: To be specific I just need to know how can I show the client the progress and just update the progress bar in html or maybe change the progress bar width style?


Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `BackGroundWorker`:

When using backgroundWorker, it is always convenient for me to use @Keith [template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74880/delegating-a-task-in-and-getting-notified-when-it-completes-in-c/75743#75743)

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true };

bw.DoWork += (sender, e) => 
   {
       //what happens here must not touch the form
       //as it's in a different thread

       //Here you should call the function that does the heavy, slow work.
       //pass the BackgroundWorker instance (bw) as an argument
   };

bw.ProgressChanged += ( sender, e ) =>
   {
       //update progress bars here
   };

bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) => 
   {
       //now you're back in the UI thread you can update the form
       //remember to dispose of bw now
   };

worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

In you function update about the progress by using something like:

```
    void YourFunction(BackgroundWorker bw)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            //do your work
            int percent = (i / length) * 100;
            bw.ReportProgress(percent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but well now the only problem would be how I'm gonna show the percent to the client exactly? (Remember It's a asp.net web-application) Thanks again. Edit: I have a loop in loops that is looping and I can exactly find out how much progress is going and trigger the update progress(percent); I just need to show to the client which I don't know how.

Comment: Actually I did not notice it is an ASP.Net application. Never the less, you can store the progress in the session and periodically check for it using a web service. For your web service you will need `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]`